# Inside onclick function not working

Tags: javascript

here i am creating the onclick function inside onclick now working

```
element.onclick = function(e) {
var div = document.getElementById("message");
var div1= document.getElementById("send");
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
button.setAttribute("value", "send");
button.setAttribute("id", candidateId);
input.name = "post";
input.maxLength = "500";
input.cols = "30";
input.rows = "10";
div.appendChild(input); //appendChild
div.appendChild(button);
console.log(button)
button.onclick = function(e) {

alert("comming")
}                       

}
```

here button.onclick function is not fired,can any one help me..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g1d26gfL/1/ -> working fine

Comment: Do you need to automatically trigger `button.onclick` ? The code works fine when manually clicking the send button.

Comment: not working,i am creating the element also dynamically in java script.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are binding the event only. If you want to fire it then trigger it after binding:

```js
element.onclick = function(e) {
  var div = document.getElementById("message");
  var div1 = document.getElementById("send");
  var input = document.createElement("textarea");
  var button = document.createElement("input");
  button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
  button.setAttribute("value", "send");
  button.setAttribute("id", candidateId);
  input.name = "post";
  input.maxLength = "500";
  input.cols = "30";
  input.rows = "10";
  div.appendChild(input); //appendChild
  div.appendChild(button);
  console.log(button)
  button.onclick = function(e) { // <-----binding is here
    alert("comming")
  }

  button.click(); // <-----trigger it here

}
```